# cpackrpm and trigger scriplets

Tags: rpm, cpack

I'm building an rpm package with cmake. The package must contain a trigger that fires when a particular version of the kernel is installed. I found that there is a %triggerin scriptlet that could be specified in the .spec file, but I didn't find the corresponding variable in cpackrpm, like CPACK_RPM_PRE_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE, CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE, etc.
Should I use CPACK_RPM_USER_BINARY_SPECFILE for trigger scriptlets, and if I use it, does that mean that CPACK_RPM_POST_INSTALL_SCRIPT_FILE variables etc. will not work, and I will need to move the code from the files they refer to into a .spec file that will be referenced by CPACK_RPM_USER_BINARY_SPECFILE?